# SQL Count Totals Within Date Ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, postgresql

I have a CHANGES table with fields VALUE(integer) and CREATED_AT(timestamp). I want to know the total of the VALUE column grouped by each of the past 30 days (without making 30 queries).

So if yesterday there were records created with VALUEs of 10, -7, and 12; I would want a record returned with CREATED_AT = yesterday and TOTAL = 15.

Any help?

Comment: You tagged 3 different database systems, which one do you really use?

Comment: mysql, but I'm hoping for a query that isn't dependent on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT date(created_at) as CREATED_AT, sum(value) as TOTAL
FROM changes
WHERE created_at >= curdate() - interval 30 day
GROUP BY date(created_at);
```

Comment: will "group by date" group by day?

Comment: Yes, date() returns day part of datetime/timestamp.

Comment: Use the constant CURRENT_DATE, that's SQL standard and works in many databases. The function curdate() is MySQL-only.

Comment: @piotrm - instead of curdate() how can we use date range to get the monthly, weekly, daily count ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it slightly depends on what kind the timestamp is formatted in (SQL/ Unix/ etc). But this type of query might help you along:

```
SELECT
   DATE_FORMAT(CREATED_AT, '%Y-%m-%d') ym,
   COUNT(VALUE)
FROM foo
GROUP BY ym
```

Comment: That's a good start--it counts the number of rows for each day. If you use SUM(VALUE) instead of COUNT(VALUE) it will add them. And if you use '%Y-%m' it will group by month. To group by 30 day periods you will need to do a bit of date math TRUNCATE(DAYS(TODAY - CREATED_AT)/30). Unfortunately TRUNCATE, DAYS, and TODAY may not be the actual names for your database.

Comment: Owh, sorry...forgot that he wanted to group them per 30 days. If it's okay to group them per month, he can just change the query to this: <code>DATE_FORMAT(CREATED_AT, '%Y-%m')</code>. This will not work if you want to stick to the 30 days and start counting those 30 days at the day of executing the query. And, @karmakaze; I don't know why you suggest the SUM(), function, but I assume that the VALUE value is just a random id. By adding those up, it says nothing about the amount of people who are celebrating their birthday that month/ 30 days.

Comment: I believe for the past 30 days part I can just add "where created_at > [30 days ago]". Sum is the function I'm looking for.

Comment: Use of SUM: the example in the question has VALUES 10, -7, and 12 which should show as 15 in the result.